# If she had or if she has a boyfriend

Tags: grammar

"If she had" or "if she has" a boyfriend?
I think it is "if she had" because the sentence  goes "if she ___ a boyfriend she would've...".  Since would've is past tense, I think the answer is "if she had a boyfriend".

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: *If she **had** one she **would** do that, but if she **has** one she **will** do this*. Or *If she **had** one she **could** do that, but if she **has** one she **can** do this*.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual 1st/2nd/3rd conditional

"If she has" is a first conditional. You don't know if she has a boyfriend or not, but you are considering the case that she does.  "If she has a boyfriend, he can pick her up after the party. If not she can get a taxi."

"If she had" is a second conditional.  You believe she doesn't have a boyfriend, but are considering the hypothetical.  This is normally followed by "..., she would".  Using "..., she would've" mixes a third conditional element, making this not only hypothetical but counterfactual.  "If she('d) had a boyfriend, she would've been picked up (but she wasn't picked up so we can deduce logically that she doesn't ahve a boyfriend)".

1st/2nd/3rd conditionals don't cover the full range of conditional expressions in English, but they are a simple model for learners to use.